# Php exec function doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, exec

I am using exec function in a php script, if I run the script in command line, such as "php xx.php", the exec function will be executed, but if i access the php page from a browser, then the exec function will not run. Anyone known how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exec function doing? If your executing the script from web, you are executing with webuser. Therefore you may be missing some rights to do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the script trying to create/edit/delete files? Try making the files and the containing directory writeable by the web server. If you're trying to add a  file, navigate to the folder you're adding it to and run the following: `chmod go+w .`. If you're trying to delete/edit a file, trying the following: `chmod go+w myfile.txt`.

When running a script from the command line it runs as the logged in user, whereas when running it through a browser it is run as the web server user (usually a user named www.) This user generally doesn't have *write* access to the files and directories that are being served.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "**2>&1**" as succeeding with the command which you are trying to execute with exec().

for example: - exec( php xx.php 2>&1", $output);

Then you can trace the problem by print output.

Comment: I tagged along "2>&1" still PHP did not display the output of command line.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `phpinfo()` output to see if safe mode is enabled. Also check to see if suhosin or mod_security are enabled. All of these can limit your ability to use `exec()`...

Comment: safe_mode is disabled, mod_security is not found in the output of exec.

Comment: try running the same script from `shell_exec()` with `./myfile.php` and make sure the file is executable from the php/apache user. e.g. `chmod g+x myfile.php`

Answer (score 0):

if you're using MAMP (to WAMP and LAMP I think that it should to be kinda similar) try open the file MAMP/Library/bin/envvar and the four lines of if and else that should looks like this:

```
#if test "x$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" != "x" ; then
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#else
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib"
```

It works for me! Good Lucky!